# "The operation would change the geometry type"

Tags: qgis, editing, file-geodatabase

I want to edit polygon features within a ESRI gdb using QGIS 3.26.2 and the FileGDB driver. When I use the Vertex Tool to e.g. move a vertex I often get the message:

> The operation would change the geometry type.

What does this mean?

I do not cut anything or create multipart features, I just move a corner that belongs to several features within the same layer.

I do want to use the functionality to reshape several features at a time by moving common vertices.

Comment: Maybe you could share a screenshot and/or a file excerpt? I guess that from simple "polygons" your edit would create "multipolygon" layer?

Comment: I get the same "The operation would change the geometry type." warning message when moving vertex in an ESRI shape file "Polygon (Multipolygon)" layer. It seems to do the edits correctly though. Using QGIS 3.22.10.

Answer (score 1):

I receive the same warning when editing multi-polygon features on a Spatial Lite layer. I am able to work around it by either modifying the vertices manually in the Vertex Editor, or using the Reshape tool in Advanced Digitizing toolset.